# How to get data from list of generic objects in type safe manner

Tags: c#, generics

I created an interface and generic class implementing that interface, so that object of the same class can hold any type of data. I created list of it successfully. But how to read data from list in type safe manner.

```
public interface Parameter
{
}

public class Parameter<T> : Parameter
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

Parameter[] parameters = new Parameter[] { 
    new Parameter<string> { Value = "X" },
    new Parameter<int> { Value = 1 },
};
```

How should I loop through array and get individual value? Parameter interface has no declaration of property Value.

Comment: you basically can't. you need to make interface generic too.but then ofcourse you can't store different types in the same collection. if you tell us what are you trying to achieve with this we may be able to help more.

Comment: I am creating a dataaccess layer for my project. I don't want to pass parameters as objects and then cast each one in dataaccess layer before seeting parameter value in command object.

Comment: Another case is to eliminate usage of DataTable while getting data from DB. I created a datastructure like "IDictionary<string, IParameter[]> columns". Here key will be column name and IParameter array will store values. Now to get value from this structure, I tried "columns["NAME"][counter].Value" but Value property is not present in Interface

Comment: @user1242604, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of ORMs like Entity Framework or NHibernate which take care of that in a much more elegant way. Or if you prefer to stay at a lower level, you can use a micro-ORM like Dapper, which just takes care of marshalling parameters and materializing entities for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a property of type `Object` in the `Parameter` interface; this will allow you to access the value, whatever its actual type:

```
public interface Parameter
{
    object Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter<T> : Parameter
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    // Explicit interface implementation
    object Parameter.Value
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set { Value = (T)value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you define this as "type safe"? What about a run-time exception caused by a setter to a value which isn't castable to `T`?

Comment: if I add "object Value { get; set; }" in interface, I have to cast it again to get values. I don't want to cast Value.

Comment: @user1242604, when you manipulate the data as `Parameter`, yes, you need to cast; but it doesn't matter, because you don't know the type anyway. When you manipulate it as `Parameter<T>`, however, you get a strongly typed property, which is only useful when you know which type you're working with.